# Cordova Android Filetransfer returning null

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

Not a fan of a double post, but here's a link to another thread:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-filetransfer-returning-null/22528

Attempting to do an android FileTransfer, plugin is working on iOS, I can't seem to get this to go!

ADB lgocat output:

```
E/PluginManager(23753): Uncaught exception from plugin
E/PluginManager(23753): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to perform an IO operation on the WebCore thread. Use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool() instead.
```

Not sure where to look next, anyone happen to be an expert? (or have any luck with the cordova-plugin-file-transfer recently?)

```
FileTransferError
body: null
code: null
exception: null
http_status: null
source: null
target: null
```

Trying a file transfer and coming back empty. Your system information:

```
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.0
Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.3.22
Xcode version: Xcode 6.3.1 Build version 6D1002 
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
ios-deploy version: 1.4.0
```

Any chance someone can post what they get for:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(FileTransfer);
        }
```

I'm seeing something nonsensical! For reference, I'm using a standard ngCordova upload: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Running in Crosswalk, not sure that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was that kit kat version bug that was happening for a while. i restricted my version of android to 21, and all my woes went away.

thank you @aorfever for your answer, it is exactly what i was doing, but ended up being something out side of the actual functions i was calling that was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using latest release of `cordova-plugin-file` and `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`, both on iOS & Android.

After injecting $cordovaFileTransfer to my Controller or Service, I call it like that :

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(myEndPoint,fileLocation, options).then(function(data){
  $log.log("Success",data);
},function(err){
  $log.warn(err);
}, function(progress) {
  $log.log(progress);
});
```

I also use on ionic ready event as I've seen that it's better as sometimes, javascript events fired a bit before ionic components are ready.

```
  ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
               myReadyCode here
            }, false);
```